# Javafx ListView Custom Cell Factory creates two objects for the first entry in observable list

Tags: listview, javafx

i am learning Custom cell factory of List View, and i have a problem. The problem is that for the first entry of items cell factory creates two Cell, it is only for the first entry, and i don't know why, may be i am doing something wrong. I would be very grateful if you pointed to what i am doing wrong.

Here is my main class:

```
public class TestMain3 extends Application {
private ObjectProperty<String> field;

public TestMain3() {

}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    ObservableList<TestMain3> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    observableList.addAll(new TestMain3("w"), new TestMain3("y"), new TestMain3("u"), new TestMain3("a"), new TestMain3("a"), new TestMain3("a"));

    System.out.println(observableList.toString() + " observable list");
    ObservableList<TestCell> testCells = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ListView<TestMain3> listView = new ListView<>();
    listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<TestMain3>, ListCell<TestMain3>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<TestMain3> call(ListView<TestMain3> param) {
            TestCell testCell = new TestCell();
            testCells.add(testCell);
            return testCell;
        }
    });
    listView.setItems(observableList);

    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.getChildren().add(listView);
    Button button = new Button("ADD");
    button.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        }
    });
    button.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    vBox.getChildren().add(button);
    Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 600, 600);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    System.out.println(testCells.toString());
}

public TestMain3(String t) {
    field = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    field.set(t);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public String getField() {
    return field.get();
}

public ObjectProperty fieldProperty() {
    return field;
}

public void setField(String field) {
    this.field.set(field);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object testMain3) {
    if (testMain3 == null) {
        return false;
    }
    TestMain3 testMain31 = (TestMain3) testMain3;
    return getField().equalsIgnoreCase(testMain31.getField());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return field.getValue().toString();
}
}
```

Here is my custom ListCell:

```
public class TestCell extends ListCell<TestMain3> {
static int counter = 0;
private String text;

public TestCell() {
    counter++;
    System.out.println(counter);
}

@Override
protected void updateItem(TestMain3 testMain3, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(testMain3, empty);
    if (empty || testMain3 == null) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
        setContextMenu(null);
    } else {
        text = testMain3.getField();
        System.out.println(testMain3 + " not null");
        setText(testMain3.getField());
    }
}

public String getTextString() {
    return text;
}

public void setTextString(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return text + " test cell";
}
}
```

And here is my output:

```
[w, y, u, a, a, a] observable list
1
w not null
2
w not null
3
y not null
4
u not null
5
a not null
6
a not null
7
a not null
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
[w test cell, w test cell, y test cell, u test cell, a test cell, a test           cell, a test cell, null test cell, null test cell, null test cell, null test   cell, null test cell, null test cell, null test cell, null test cell, null test cell, null test cell, null test cell, null test cell]
```

So as you can see in my observable list i have only one W, however listview created two W, even though it doesn't show in listview, it creates some problems.

**UPDATE**

I do remove listeners when list is reused.

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Contact contact, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(contact, empty);
    if (empty || contact == null) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
        setContextMenu(null);
    } else {
         registerListeners(contact);
        .....
     }
}
```

registerListeners method

```
private void registerListeners(Contact contact) {
   if (person != null) {    
     person.getChat().newMessagesCountProperty().
            removeListener(newMessagesChangeListener);
     person.getChat().getMessages().
            removeListener(chatMessagesListChangeListener);
     onlineIconView.visibleProperty().unbind();
   }
   person = contact;
   onlineIconView.visibleProperty().bind(contact.onlineProperty());               
   person.getChat().newMessagesCountProperty().
           addListener(newMessagesChangeListener);
   person.getChat().getMessages().
           addListener(chatMessagesListChangeListener);
}
```

I am creating a chat application, the problem is when the first person in the listview gets new message its cell should be updated showing icon of new message and number of new messages, however its listener gets called twice thus it looks like user got two new messages, whereas in fact he only got one.
And there is no problem with contacts after the first one

**UPDATE2**
for now in the `updateItem()` if it is the first not null cell, i just return doing nothing, so for me it solved my problem. I think this is a bug.

Comment: You could use an `ObservableList` with an [extractor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList-java.util.List-javafx.util.Callback-). That way the `updateItem(...)` method would be called when any of the properties you specify change, and you wouldn't need to manage the listeners at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong here.

The only responsibility of the cell factory and the `ListCell`s it creates are to create enough cells to fill the `ListView`, and to call `updateItem(...)` whenever the item displayed by a cell changes. No guarantees are made as to how many cells are actually created and how many times `updateItem(...)` is called on each cell.

Since you observe only one cell is displayed with `"w"` as its text, the cell factory and cells are working correctly.

The fact that you see `updateItem(...)` called with the parameter whose field is `"w"` twice is just a side-effect of the way the cell factory mechanism is implemented in the version of JavaFX you are using. It's possible that you may observe different behavior in other versions.

The only things you really need to know about this are:

- Don't assume anything specific about how many times `updateItem(...)` is called on a particular cell. In particular, there is no one-to-one correspondence between items in the list view and cells that are displayed, so `updateItem(...)` will be called multiple times to reuse the cells (e.g. during scrolling).
- Cells are created rarely (typically, only when the `ListView` is first displayed, but possibly also when the `ListView` increases in height)
- `updateItem(...)` may be called very frequently (e.g. as the user scrolls in the `ListView`). Consequently, don't do any performance-intensive work in `updateItem(...)`

Comment: i know that cell factory creates as many as cells as it needs, and that these cells are virutalized and reused(by calling `updateItem(..)` on each), however as you can see from output it created two different Cells and called on both of them `updateItem()` with the same parameters(TestMain3("w")). Thus i have 7 cells with not null values, whereas in observable list i have only 6

Comment: Yes, I see that. It's strange, perhaps, but it doesn't violate any of the declared functionality. What is the actual issue?

Comment: in the beginning of `updateItem(...)` i bind some listeners to my object(of course if it is not null), based on those listeners it should change the cell appearance(ui) , and in my situation i think this first two Cells overlap or something like that, and i don't get desired UI change. with other cells it is ok.

Comment: If you don't remove the listeners, you will have a bug because the cell will be listening to multiple items after cell reuse. Post some code.